# How to leave a set number of spaces in NSString?

Tags: objective-c, replace, nsstring, space

I have separate text objects for the unchanging portion (i.e. "Bonus Score:    (+7%)") and the changing portion (e.g. "247,890"). Since they're separate, I want to leave space in the unchanging portion to display the number.

What I first tried was:

```
NSString* numberString = @"247,890";
NSString* blankScore = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:[numberString length] withString: @" " startingAtIndex:0];
NSString* baseDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BONUS SCORE: %@ (+7%%)", blankScore];
```

'blankScore' was the correct length, but the resulting baseDisplay seemed to trim the spaces around where blankScore would be, making it too small of a space for the displayed number.

Next I tried another way of creating blankScore:

```
NSString* blankScore = [numberString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [numberString length]) withString:@" "];
```

But this returned a blankScore of length 1.

Am I understanding these NSString methods incorrectly? I checked the docs, and it seems like my understanding of these methods aligns with what's written there, but I still don't understand why I can't get my baseDisplay to have the correct number of spaces.

Comment: Why not simply use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%8d", score]` or alike?

Comment: I want to manipulate the displayed score and the baseDisplay differently (graphics-wise), so I don't want to have the actual score number be part of baseDisplay and am instead trying to find a way to leave a set number of blank spaces.

Comment: "There's a format specifier for that"... `"%*d", numOfSpaces, score`

Comment: I don't think this works if I only want spaces and no number. If I put @" " in place of 'score' in your short code snippet (and replace d with @), I get only 1 space still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you printed `blankScore` on the console using `NSLog`? Actually your string is correct, but the output is trimmed at end of lines - this is why you see it as described.

Comment: I did that soon after I posted this actually, and based on the console, it looks pretty good, but when it's displayed on my screen, it's still scrunched, so it may be a problem in translating that to the graphics. Should I take this question down since the problem may be somewhere else? I'm still also interested as to why the second method returned a string of length 1.

Comment: stringByReplacingCharactersInRange returns a new string in which the characters in a specified range of the receiver are replaced by a given string. While this replaces "247,890" with " " it's length is expected to be 1.

Comment: I just chose your response as an answer since you confirmed that my string is correct, and I definitely think the problem lies with how my foundation code is displaying the text. Hopefully the rest of the discussion on this page will help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

@H2CO3 is on to the right solution. You should be using: 
   NSString *baseDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BONUS SCORE: %@ (+7%%)", numberString];

To make this work even better, you may want to consider an NSNumberFormatter to correctly format the changing part before inserting it into the baseDisplay object. Something like this:

```
NSNumber *changingNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:247890];
NSNumberFormatter *correctFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[correctFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[correctFormat setHasThousandSeparators:YES];
[correctFormat setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];

NSString *numberString = [correctFormat stringFromNumber:changingNumber];
NSString *baseDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BONUS SCORE: %@ (+7%%)", numberString];
```

This way no matter what number you throw at it, it will correctly display "1,234,456" or "34,567", whatever.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments to my answer you will need to use:

```
stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:
```

It should look something like this:

```
NSString *templateString = @"BONUS SCORE:";
NSString *templateString2 = @"(+7%%)";
NSUInteger baseStringLength = [templateString length] + [numberString length];
NSString *spacedString = [templateString stringByPaddingToLength:baseStringLength withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
NSString *baseDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", spacedString, templateString2];
```

Comment: Your second solution returned '1' because you replaced the entire string with a single space.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your answer, but my reasons for keeping the score separate from the other text kept me from taking @H2C03's suggestion. Please see the comment I posted under H2CO3's comment.

Comment: I believe the part you added under EDIT: is incorrect. My program started crashing, and then I remembered that startingAtIndex: takes an index for the position in whatever string you pass withString:, which means 13 is out of bounds for @" ".

Comment: Sorry about that. It's been a while since I've used that method. I have updated it to reflect proper usage. I ran it through a test XCode project and it worked fine.